# Google Charts Stacked Bar Chart using CHM an CHD options

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

i have got a stacked bar chart using Google charts.
i need to display values within each bar, the role: annotation option displays the values at the edge of each section, i need to display the value in the middle of each option. i know i could use chm or chd, but i don't know where to put those options within java-script. 
i have looked at the google documentation and it talks about the 'Text and Data Value Markers chm' but doesnt give an example how to use these markers within javascript.

chm=   N,FF0000,-1,,12|   N,000000,0,,12,,c|   N,000000,1,,12,,c|   N,ffffff,2,,12,,c

Comment: Those options are only valid for the Image Chart API, not for the Visualization API.  The Visualization API does not support changing the position of annotations.

Comment: is there any way to achieve that in the visualization API, to put text in the middle of the a bar chart for instance

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can hack around the problem to move the annotations, but it's not pretty or elegant, it doesn't work in all cases, and in my opinion, the results don't look good.  Here's an example of it so you can see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/8TkVt/